# Bootstrap NavBar not aligned, especially in mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, responsive-design, navbar

My navbar seems to go out of whack. It's especially evident when I view the site on my mobile device, or just shrink my desktop window.

Below is a link to my site along with the code. I would love for my name to fit between my projects tap on the left and my e-mail and twitter icons on the right.  Thank you for your help and time.

http://jocatcreative.com/

[image: http://i.imgur.com/0UpNGnU.jpg]

(trying to get past stack socials 2 link limit...

imugr dot com/0s4iJyr

imgur dot com/vqjiyEd)

(Edited to include screenshots)

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container">

            <div class="Heading Tag" align="center"><h2>Jovan S Hernandez</h2></div>


  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         data-target="#example-navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
   </div>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="example-navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
         <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Projects <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="#">JoCat Creative Media</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Gesaffelstein Landing</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Monthly  Resolutions</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li class="divider"></li>
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>


          <ul class="pull-right">
            <a href="mailto:jovanshernandez@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email Me</a>
            <a href="http://www.twitter.com/jovansn0w"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a>
          </ul>
      </div><!-- .container --> 
    </div><!-- .navbar -->
```

Comment: How exactly is it "out of whack"? What I'm seeing and what you're seeing could be completely different. Please include a screen shot of the problem if you can, or a better description of the actual problem, and what you'd like it to look like.

Comment: MattD- edited to include screenshots. Hope they help!-- I want my landing page nav bar to all be on the same line.. as you can see, my name, the twitter/email icons, and my left nav bar are all on seperate lines... 

As for mobile, the nav bar is on the right, then when opened, everything is all over the place. I would like for them to either be all on the left side if viewed on mobile. -- I don't even care exactly how they are aligned, I would just like it to look aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### DEMO: https://jsbin.com/qufelu/1/

*https://jsbin.com/qufelu/1/edit?html,css,output*

You were using some incorrect classes, missing tags (on the right aligned stuff), unclosed tag (collapse), and were using an outdated attribute from ancient history ( `align="center"`) Also, you don't need to wrap the name inside a div.

**CSS**

```
.custom-navbar {
    background: transparent;
    border: 0px;
}
@media (max-width:767px) { 
    .custom-navbar .name {
        font-size: 20px;
        float: left;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 15px 0 15px 15px;
    }
    .custom-navbar .navbar-toggle {
        margin: 10px 15px 0 0;
        float: right;
    }
}
@media (min-width:768px) { 
    .custom-navbar .navbar-header {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .custom-navbar .name {
        text-align: center;
        float: none;
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default custom-navbar">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <h2 class="name">Jovan S Hernandez</h2>
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
            data-target="#navbar-collapse">
         <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         <span class="icon-bar"></span>
         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
         <ul class="navbar-right nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="mailto:jovanshernandez@gmail.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Email Me</a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/jovansn0w"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i> Twitter</a></li>
         </ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <li class="dropdown">
               <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Projects <b class="caret"></b>
               </a>
               <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><a href="#">JoCat Creative Media</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Gesaffelstein Landing</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Monthly  Resolutions</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
      <!-- .navbar-collapse --> 
   </div>
   <!-- .container --> 
</div>
<!-- .navbar -->
```